# Java - Printing a message when data exceeds limit?

Tags: java, stack, queue, message

I've got my code working, it's not pretty but it doe's the job :) Now I want to write a piece of code that stops the data from being loaded if there is 19 or more pieces of data in the text file and then display a message saying Invalid input for example. I'm not sure how to do this so any help would be appreciated.

```
package stackandqueue;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StackAndQueue {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Create three empty stacks of Bays.
        // Bay 1 linked list
        Queue<String> bayoneStack = new LinkedList<String>();
        // Bay 2 linkd list.
        Queue<String> baytwoStack = new LinkedList<String>();
        // Bay 3 linked list
        Queue<String> baythreeStack = new LinkedList<String>();

        Queue<String> bayloadStack = new LinkedList<String>();

        System.out.println("***********************************************");

        // Open and read text file
        String inputFileName = "PodData4.txt";
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("PodData4.txt");

        // Create the FileReader object
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);) {
            // Sort the data into the relevant linked list by type F, T or P.
            String[] strings = br.readLine().split(",");
            for (String str : strings) {
                switch (str.charAt(0)) {
                case 'F':
                    bayoneStack.add(str);
                    break;
                case 'T':
                    baytwoStack.add(str);
                    break;
                case 'P':
                    baythreeStack.add(str);
                    break;
                default:
                    // In-case of invalid input

                }

                System.out.println(str);

            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception;
        } finally {
            fileReader.close();
        }
        // Prints out the linked list stacks showing all Bays.
        System.out.println("***********************************************");

        System.out.println("Bay 1:Food: " + bayoneStack.toString());
        System.out.println("Bay 2:Technical: " + baytwoStack.toString());
        System.out.println("Bay 3:Personal: " + baythreeStack.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: I would count the number of pieces of data and print the message when the counter exceeds 19.  Could you be more specific as to what problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

Just check the overall length first with a conditional statement. Something like

```
String test = br.readLine();
if (test.length() < 19) {
    String[] strings = test.split(",");
    //continue operations with string input
}
else {
    //change this to what you want the error to read.
    System.out.println("Invalid input.");
}
```

Note that I changed your `strings` array to split the `test` string instead of `br.readLine()`